# Mvc Update Many to Many relation when have Multilingual Database Design

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework-6

I'm using mvc5 using by entity framework 6.0 with mysql data.entity 6.9.9 , the question that is the brain twister for all day.

Here is my code to creating a category

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CategoryAdd(CategoryModel category, int Lang_Id)
{
    var dbCategory = _categoryrepo.GetAll().Select(x => x.CategoryName.Trim().ToUpper());
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (dbCategory.Contains(category.CategoryName.Trim().ToUpper()))
        {

            return Json(new ResultJson { Success = false, Message = "This Category already created ! Please Try again..." });
        }
        try
        {
            category CatModel = new category
            {

                CategoryName = category.CategoryName,
                IsActive = true

            };
            _categoryrepo.Insert(CatModel);
            _categoryrepo.Save();
            var languagecount = db.language.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
            foreach (var LangCount in languagecount)
            {
                category_translation model = new category_translation()
                {
                    CategoryName = category.CategoryName,
                    category_ID = CatModel.ID,
                    language_ID = LangCount.ID,
                    urlFriendly = StringOperations.URLFriendly(CatModel.CategoryName)
                };
                db.category_translation.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            category_translation updateCategoryTranslation = db.category_translation.Where(r => r.language_ID == Lang_Id && r.category_ID == CatModel.ID).SingleOrDefault();
            updateCategoryTranslation.language_ID = Lang_Id;
            updateCategoryTranslation.CategoryName = category.CategoryTranlatedText;
            updateCategoryTranslation.urlFriendly = StringOperations.URLFriendly(category.CategoryTranlatedText);
            db.SaveChanges();


            return Json(new ResultJson {Success = true, Message = "'"+ CatModel.CategoryName +"'" + " Created Successfully "});
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //Logging will be included by Elmah
        {
            return Json(new ResultJson {Success = false, Message = "Error Occured When Trying to Create Category! Please try again or contact with tour administrator..."});
        }
    }
    return Json(new ResultJson { Success = false, Message = "While you are Creating the category you might be entered wrong values! Please Try Again..." });
}
```

And in the view of course Im using mvc validation with jquery.

Right now I have 48 table to add values to them which they related many to many. 
Lets assume that in the future I had added 208 table and each table have multilingual option to save the data to database

*Example Table:*
[image: the table]

**The Question is**: Should I do the saving method with **async task** or that implementation is not affected to system too many treatment

hint: At least 12 user will be save the data at the same time.

note: I know it is too less may be but as a question if the project will grow and the user will be over 100 and tables over 400. What will happen?

Comment: Why do you have hundreds of tables?  That _usually_ is a sign of a poor schema design.

Comment: `hospital_has_branch` is a separate table, as if it is "many-to-many".  But the name sounds more like 1:many, as in each hospital has many branches.  In that case, you should not use an extra table.

Comment: There is also multi language table and in the scenario 
I am talking about in here  if 100 of work mean table will I have. Don't think that only hospital management is happening in that database example if I will implement Stock management or patients management in that database and each table have connect with them to have fk and etc. That's why the database table can be more than even 20 hundred table base on the requirements. I hope you understand what I mean 100 tables are about